# Forcing C#'s HTTP Response to Return a Status Code Instead of a Description

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I am currently using this script to get HTTP response headers.

```
public static List<string> GetHttpResponseHeaders(string url)
{
    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
    WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int) ((HttpWebResponse) webResponse).StatusCode);
    }
    return headers;
}
```

Specifically, `Status Code:` is what I am interested in. With that said, it appears that `StatusCode()` doesn't actually return a "status code," and on successful requests, it only returns an `OK` instead of a `200`.

Is there a way to force it to return the actual code instead of a description?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With that said, it appears that StatusCode() doesn't actually return a "status code," and on successful requests, it only returns an OK instead of a 200.

No, it returns an [`HttpStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum value. If you call `ToString` on an enum value that has a name, it will return the name.

The simplest way of avoiding that is just to cast it to `int`:

```
headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int) ((HttpWebResponse) webResponse).StatusCode);
```

Or to make the rest of the block cleaner, cast the response once:

```
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webResponse;
    headers.Add("URL: " + url);
    headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int) httpResponse.StatusCode);
    headers.Add("Status Description: " + httpResponse.StatusDescription + "\n");
}
```

(Note that when you're using string concatenation, `ToString` will be called implicitly if necessary - and it's never worth calling on something like `StatusDescription` which is already a string.)

Comment: This worked for me - thanks Jon. I'm at a bit of a fork right now. Is there any difference between doing this: `HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);` and this `WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Well, they don't change which object is created. The first will throw an exception if the return value isn't an `HttpWebRequest`. If you're not using any of the HTTP-specific members, there's no point in casting really.

Comment: I see, I understand now. Thanks Jon! One more question if you don't mind - it appears some errors that I've encountered with requesting headers can be fixed with something as simple as adding a Cookie Container to my `HttpWebRequest` properties. For example, this fixes the `too many automatic redirection were attempted` error. Are there any resources written on "best practices" for forming a HTTP web request so we can avoid these common errors?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: I don't know of any, I'm afraid. I'm not an expert on that sort of thing :(

Comment: I've been Googling everywhere (I can't be the first person ever to encounter this issue!) to find out the C# standards, but I suppose everyone are using external libraries to help them craft these responses. Any idea where I can find out? I've trawled MSDN as well, but no dice :(.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: I'm not sure there are external libraries around this - but I'd be doing the same sort of searches as you.

Answer (score 2):

`StatusCode` is an [`HttpStatusCode` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode).

You can cast it to `int` to get the underlying value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the value "OK" is because property [`HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is of type [`HttpStatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - an enumeration. Calling `.ToString()` on an enumeration will give you text, not a number.

So, while you're not seeing the numeric value of the status code, you are seeing a representation of the status code, and not the status description.

If you need the integer value, you can cast the enum to `int` (`HttpStatusCode.OK` does indeed have a value of `200`) - but it's worth considering that there's no guarantee that the integer values of the enum will line up with the status code values.