# Web Exception from requesting headers is returning the status code description but not the error

Tags: c#, header

We are interested in catching the `status code` + `status code description` which describes the error when catching our exceptions in the event that a user encounters a connection error. This method prints out the web exceptions in that event in a message box (not shown here).

Why is it not showing the status code?

```
internal static List<string> getHeaders(string url, string postdata)
        {
            List<string> headers = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.Timeout = 20000;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                Stream newstream = request.GetRequestStream();
                newstream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                HttpWebResponse httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int)httpresponse.StatusCode);
                headers.Add("Status Desc: " + httpresponse.StatusDescription);
                foreach (string key in response.Headers.Keys)
                {
                    if (!key.ToString().Equals("Location"))
                    {
                        var value = httpresponse.Headers[key];
                        headers.Add(key + ": " + value);
                    }
                }

                return headers;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                headers.Add("ERROR MESSAGE: " + ex.Message);
                return headers;
            }
        }
```

This is in reference to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607706/forcing-cs-http-response-to-return-a-status-code-instead-of-a-description) which shows us the status code AND the status code description when `try-catching` headers.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it appears the code works just fine. The error returned that was `the remote name could not be resolved` however does not return a status code.